# Integral ring homomorphisms exercise

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ring-homomorphism

A,B,C-rings;
f:A->B integral ring homomorphism, g: B->C integral ring homomorphism; prove that g(f):A->C is also integral.

I had no trouble to prove for word "finite" instead of integral but I fail so far for word "integral"

Comment: I can't remember to have seen a textbook in Commutative Algebra that doesn't prove this.

Comment: I've just looked over Eisenbud's book and did not find it, however I did not read 700 pages. I will try myself again.